# Codeigniter 2 and .htaccess - how to implement "down for maintenance" mode?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know this question might have been asked a few times already, but I need a specific solution for CodeIgniter, using an .htaccess file that would send every request to an index_failsafe.php file instead of the normal index.php but ONLY if the url doesn't start with 'admin'. Example:

1. www.myhost.com/admin -> work as usual
2. www.myhost.com/welcome -> sent to failsafe page

in case 1:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

in case 2:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index_failsafe.php/$1 [L]
```

My rewrite conditions are:

```
   RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I do it by IP - so I can take my site offline, but I still have full access to it (to test new functions and make sure it is working before bringing back up)

```
RewriteEngine on

    # For maintenance:
    # If your IP address is 1.1.1.1 - then dont re-write
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.1\.1\.1
    # If the person is requesting the maintenance page, also dont rewrite (prevent loops)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ 
    # Otherwise rewrite all requests to the maintenance page
    RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]


    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(assets)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|maintenance\.html)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

just change !^1.1.1.1 to your current IP. i.e. !^121.65.56.65

If your not sure what your IP is - just google "what is my IP" - and it will show up as the first hit

But in terms of your specific question - this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin$ 
RewriteRule $ /index_failsafe.php [R=302,L]
```

edit:

Comment: what does the 2nd RewriteCond do? 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$`

Comment: I've editted my answer to insert comments, but that line basically says "hey, if they are requesting the maintenance page, dont re-write them back to the maintenance page" - i.e. prevent loops

Comment: What is `crossdomain.xml`?

Comment: @Sparky you can ignore that - it was for one of my specific requirements. It is not needed for this solution.

Comment: If it's superfluous, pull it out, no?

Comment: Ok - I've pulled it out :)

Comment: Great answer. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use cookies to store session data for users then it might be simpler to change the cookie name to force everyone to log out, then change the login page controller to load a view that says "down for maintenance" or whatever.

When you're done just change the cookie name back to what it was and everyone will still be logged in, and make sure to change back the view that the login page controller loads so users can log in normally.

To change the session cookie for CI, open up config.php and change the value for:

```
    $config['sess_cookie_name']
```

You can take it a step further by creating an alternate login controller and view titled "maintenance login" or something like that, and then you can still log in for testing.

This is the method that I use when I need to take my saas down for maintenance, and it works great. Our public facing sales page is unaffected, and I don't have to mess with htaccess.